# Why does the Apollo reentry trajectory show a few climbs?

Tags: apollo-program, reentry

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34648/9072) the following graph is displayed:

[image: Reentry trajectory]

It shows two slight increases in altitude (after 1st peak g and at the end of the blackout). For me, it looks like [zoom climbs](https://www.av8n.com/how/htm/energy.html#sec-energy-conversion) (trading kinetic energy (velocity) for potential energy (altitude)) made to slow down the space craft, but I cannot find any evidence.

What is the purpose of these climbs? Is it to slow down the spacecraft? Is it a common maneuver used during reentry (i.e. is the Apollo spacecraft the only one performing such maneuver)?

Comment: See the answers to these questions [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/how-does-skipping-off-the-atmosphere-work), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/mathematically-what-is-the-argument-in-favor-of-skipping-reentries/19648#19648).

Comment: There's a lot of confusion about this - you'll see "aborted skip entry", "double dip entry", etc, etc. This is a great question and I'd love to see somebody write up the definitive answer. Sadly I'm not that guy. +1

Comment: Not directly on point, but this Instrumentation Lab paper on the reentry guidance system has some interesting context: https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/R-415%20Apollo%20Reentry%20Guidance.pdf

Comment: I'm also not that guy, but that guy might enjoy reading [Apollo Experience Report: Mission Planning for Apollo Entry](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19720013191.pdf).

Comment: Have a look at [What are the three peaks in this Apollo reentry heating plot?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31553/12102) I think there may be some connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly trading kinetic energy for potential energy is an inevitable part of the process. In general this is important in controlling heating and g-forces. A fully ballistic re-entry would have only one (high) max g-force. Attempting to "pull-up" to achieve this is pretty universal. Its worth noting that there is nothing special about an ever-so-slight inflection of the trajectory, its all a spectrum.

That said, its unlikely that bobbing is ever the truly optimal solution, but the causes to do so range from: adding scope for altering trajectory, to being conservative on risking dipping too deep too soon and having too high peak g-force or heating.

As the actual trajectory is a result of all these competing factors, and the (in-)accuracy, of implementing them its unlikely you'll get a short and accurate answer for *exactly* "why" a particular path was taken.

Comment: This is pretty generic- the question is more specific to that flight. All of those factors couldve contributed but theres no source linked here that states definitively that they did. Possibly a NASA writeup on the trajectory would be published context that could definitively answer OP.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: it seems a generic question to me. the actual question bit is: "What is the purpose of these climbs? Is it to slow down the spacecraft? Is it a common maneuver used during reentry (i.e. is the Apollo spacecraft the only one performing such maneuver)?"